# Multisite - User creation for second site from first site?

Tags: multisite, user-registration

I have two different WP sites set up in my multisite network.

The website #1 should act as the frontend of the multisite and website #2 is the members section.

If a user fills out the form on website #1 it is not needed that the user is registered for website #1, he should only be registered for website #2. Is there any function that I can use to do this?

I found:

- register_new_user = It registers the user for website #1
- add_user_to_blog = It adds the user from website #1 to website #2
- wpmu_signup_user = It adds the user to the multisite admin panel.

There is not a function which is like register_new_user to only do this for website #2, is it?

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you're using the built-in registration form, you should be able to hook into the `user_register` action, which receives the `$user_id` of the newly created user as an argument. Use `get_current_blog_id()` to check if the user was created on site #1 and, if so, use `add_user_to_blog()` and `remove_user_from_blog()` to "move" them to site #2.

Comment: Hey, yep - I did it like that now and it works like a charm. However I thought there might be another function that does this automatically. Thanks!